# SQL query to get the latest price from the data?

Tags: sql, oracle, function, case

I have this data in my Oracle table:

[image]

In this table, I have multiple products with having `product_id` and price at a particular time.

I want to write a SQL query to get latest price of each product based on the `TIME` column (Oracle - Long Type).

But here is the problem, for our table price monitoring for the product starts at 23:00 previous date.

Output required: when I passed 2-Dec-2019 as parameter into the SQL query

[image]

How can I do this with a SQL query? Or do I need to write a stored procedure for it, based on if and else condition?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `But here is the problem` ... You appear to be taking results for 19-Dec both before and after 11pm.  Please explain your logic.

Comment: @Tim Date  is not 19 Dec. It is 2019

Comment: Sorry, it is 2nd Dec 2019, but my question still stands.

Comment: @Tim Let me explain the logic: I want the latest price for every product. Now I will pass date as parameter in my query. However, I need to consider  all rows where time is more than 230000(hhmmss) and previous date. You can see the output i have shown. For product Id 13520,  time is 231150 and local_date is 1-Dec . So when I pass 2-Dec as parameter in my sql query, you can see there is no other row for 13520 id, i want to consider that row as latest as that is after 230000.

Comment: In case, if it is not clear I will explain with more data..

Comment: Define the dates and hours that logically make up 2nd Dec 2019, according to your data.

Comment: Isn't it simply the latest price until 2019-12-02 (including) you are looking for per product? Or would you dismiss a product the last price entry of which were 2019-11-30?

Comment: As an aside, keeping 'time' in a LONG data type is a serious design flaw in your data model.  While oracle doesn't have a distinct TIME type, its DATE always contains time, down to the second (TIMESTAMP is date and time down to the nano-second).  The only proper type to use for time is DATE (or TIMESTAMP, depending on the time resolution).  If the usage truly needs time only (really doesn't care about the date) then you'd still use DATE and just ignore the date component.  If you do care about the date with the time, then use a single DATE column.  And ALWAYS use 4-digit years!

Comment: @Thorsten I am not interested in the date 2019-11-30. For my business case, today's price is considered from "previous date 23:00"  to "today's date until 23:00"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try using `ROW_NUMBER` for this requirement:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY time DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable t
    WHERE system_date = date '2019-12-19'
)

SELECT local_date, system_date, currency, product_id, time, current_price
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I see.  You can use two parameters in the `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT local_date, system_date, currency, product_id, time, current_price
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product_id
                                ORDER BY local_date DESC, time DESC
                               ) as seqnum
      FROM t
      WHERE system_date = @parameter
     ) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

I'm not sure if you really want the filtering on date like that.  You might want:

```
      WHERE system_date <= @parameter
```

or:

```
      WHERE system_date < @parameter + interval '1' day
```

These would allow you to get data from earlier days, if there is no data on the date specified by the parameter.  The second version also works if `system_date` has a time component (which is allowed for `date` data types in Oracle).

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are storing date and time separately, which makes working with the date and time more complicated than needed.

One way to combine the two:

```
local_date + interval '1' second * (to_number(substr(time, 5, 2)) +
                                    to_number(substr(time, 3, 2)) * 60 +
                                    to_number(substr(time, 1, 2)) * 3600)
```

Another:

```
to_date(to_char(local_date, 'yyyymmdd') || time, 'yyyymmddhh24miss')
```

With this datetime you want something along the lines of

```
where the_time >= timestamp '2019-12-01 23:00:00' and the_time < date '2019-12-03'
```

For some date yet unknown that will be provided when running the query:

```
where the_time >= :date - interval '1' hour and the_time < :date + interval '1' day
```

For the current day, supposing there is no future data in the table:

```
where the_time >= trunc(sysdate) - interval '1' hour
```

As to preferring a more current datetime over an older one, use a window function, e.g. `MAX OVER`.

```
with rows_with_datetime as
(
  select
    mytable.*, 
    to_date(to_char(local_date, 'yyyymmdd') || time, 'yyyymmddhh24miss') as dt
  from mytable
)
, two_days_with_maxdatetime as
(
  select
    rows_with_datetime.*,
    max(dt) over (partition by product_id order by dt) as max_dt
  from rows_with_datetime
  where dt >= trunc(sysdate) - interval '1' hour
)
select *
from two_days_with_maxdatetime
where dt = max_dt
order by product_id;
```

As the datetime gets calculated, no index will be used here and the query may be quite slow accordingly. So, you should better change the data model to have a datetime you can easily index and work with instead of separate date and time. If you can't, you may want to apply an additional redundant condition on the date alone:

```
where local_date >= trunc(sysdate) - interval '1' day
```

Answer (score 0):

You may extend the idea from other answer (using `ROW_NUMBER`) to define a *view* providing only the records with the last price per day.

You must provide you dimensions (product_id and day) in the `PARTITION BY` clause, which will work for any product and any day - selecting only the row with the *highest time per day and product*.

```
create view last_price_per_day as 
with last_price as (
select 
  SYSTEM_DATE, PRODUCT_ID, TIME, CURRENT_PRICE,
  row_number() over (partition by PRODUCT_ID, SYSTEM_DATE order by TIME desc) as rn
from tab)
select 
  SYSTEM_DATE, PRODUCT_ID, TIME, CURRENT_PRICE
from last_price
where rn = 1;
```

Note that this approach is superior to altervatives using `MAX(TIME)` in correlated subquery, as it works fine even if ties occurres (more rows with the same highest time).

If this is a relevant topic, you may add further columns to the `ORDER BY` clause, e.g. by adding `CURRENT_PRICE DESC` you will get the highest price from the tied rows.

**A good check** for such *last row* views is to verify if the columns in `PARTITIEN BY` and `ORDER BY`  are unique in the table.

In your case `PRODUCT_ID, SYSTEM_DATE, TIME` should be unique, otherwise the view **is not deterministic** and will **return on repeated queries different results** - which may be not what you expect.